# Powerpoint macro editor (VB for application) does not support Non-Ascii characters suddenly

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, non-ascii

It was all ok for many years but it has just happened since few days ago.

The macro editor (VB for application) of Powerpoint 365 does not support Non-Ascii characters any more suddenly.

It was ok but all non-ascii characters input becomes ??????? now!

[image]

Want to try it by yourself? This is a sample of non-ascii characters: **中文**. You can copy it any test it.

During this period of time, no setting changes were made, so it is suspected that it was caused by the recent update.

Or, is there new preference setting lost and should be set?

The current version is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If non-English characters have stopped displaying correctly,
it's probably because you have changed your Windows Region to
an English region, or to some other region that does not support
the language of the characters.

The VBA editor does not support Unicode encoding. It uses instead
[ANSI code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)
for supporting international characters.
Its character encoding is simply the code page that is used as
function of the Windows Locale, as specified in
*Control Panel > Region*.

When entering non-English characters, for example Chinese, you will
get a string of question marks, even if Chinese is included in
your language preferences.

If you wish to return to the time that non-English characters
were correctly displayed in VBE, you need to reset your Region
to what it was before,
or at least to some region that supports the language of these
characters.

This situation is frustrating in the 21st century,
but Excel is a very old product, and so is VBA.

Comment: No, there is no any change at all.

Comment: Try in *Control Panel > Programs and Features* to right-click Office and select Repair (or Change).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when writing/debugging a VBA add-in for a customer in China.

Try this:

You'll need to restart the computer for the new setting to take effect, so be sure to save your work and close any open programs.  Then:

Control Panel | Region
Administrative tab
Under Language for non-Unicode programs, click Change System Locale.
Choose the appropriate language for your situation; if using Chinese, be sure to select the appropriate option ... simplified/traditional/etc.

Let it restart your computer. After the restart, the default font in the VBA IDE will have changed ( a bit spidery looking to my taste, but liveable ) and you'll be able to display e.g. Chinese text.